# How to open URL in WebView through .js in cocos creator

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I want to open any url like this(https://example.com/mPayment/api.php?playerid=name&method=init)
in my WebView through script coding not from design view in CocosCreator.
I have done this code but its not opening what I am doing wrong,

```
var url =  "https://example.com/mPayment/api.php?playerid=name&method=init";
        this.webPage._url = url;
        console.log("Webview1111111  ==== ", this.webPage._url);
```

and on url there is name where I want to pass the player ID.
Acutely I want to implement Payment gateway in my cocos creator game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine:

```
this.webView.url = this.editBox.string;
```

Maybe you forget to bind webView to UI element in the designer.